# How might I select cross-domain links in my user stylesheet?

Tags: css, google-chrome, cross-domain

Using a user stylesheet, I want to put a special icon before any link that takes me to a different domain from any website(e.g. *example.com* to *example1.example.com*, *example.com* to *stackoverflow.com*, *example.com* to *example.com:80*,*http://example.com* to *https://example.com* etc. **but not** example.com/patha to example.com/pathb). How would I do this? I already know that to put the image before a link, I must use something like

```
a:before
{
content:url(path/to/icon.png);
}
```

I have tried it and made sure it works, but how would I make it select only cross-domain links? My limitations are to that of the user style sheet in Chrome, meaning **no scripts** unless I can specify a user-written script without turning it into an extension.
I've tried `a[href^=http]:before` but a) not every website puts protocol in front of urls and b) websites can link to themselves with the protocols.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found the perfect solution to your problem.

Sadly, it's in CSS4, and we're still waiting for all of CSS3.

Here's the code anyway, as found in [w3 specs](http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors4/#local-pseudo);

```
a:not(:local-link(0)):before {
    content:url(path/to/icon.png);
}
```